# How to see the ip of visitors when they click on share button javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins

I work with Wordpress-
On my site I added the plugin addtoany- share button. I want to know what is the IP of the visitor when they click on share button and any other link like: YouTube, twitter, twitch etc. also, if i can get more details like: country, ISP etc. 
I can add code in "JavaScript" into the plugin.